# How to find maximum and minimum value in an array of integers in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have an array with values *33, 32, 8, 100*.

How can I find the maximum and minimum value in this array?

Do I need to include any special libraries?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util)'s `min` and `max` are fine,

```
use List::Util qw( min max );
my $min = min @numbers;
my $max = max @numbers;
```

But [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils)'s `minmax` is more efficient when you need both the min and the max (because it does fewer comparisons).

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );
my ($min, $max) = minmax @numbers;
```

List::Util is part of core, but List::MoreUtils isn't.

Answer (score 24):

Without modules:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = sort { $a <=> $b } qw(33 32 8 100);
print "min: $array[0]\n";
print "max: $array[-1]\n";
```

Comment: This spends a bit of time ordering values that are in between the min & max that it may have already encountered, taking O(N log N) time when it should only take O(N) time.

Comment: Programming inside Webwork, that uses Apache Perl, without modules I do not have "sort". How can I go around this?

Comment: @Echeban the `sort` is an internal function of every perl, **no** modules needed. Check `perldoc -f sort` or `man perlfunc`.

Comment: Webwork uses Apache Perl and throws this error `ERRORS from evaluating PG file: 
 'sort' trapped by operation mask at line 20 of (eval 2211)` In Webwork, anything that is not valid Perl (in their context) is thus  *trapped*

Comment: @Echeban Because the sort's comparison code could be potentionally unsafe, then the PG throws error. Check [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20051006011134.GA7542%40fetter.org) and probably more on the internet.

Or ask here one additional and error-specific question - because i'm not an PG expert, nor Webwork expert, so I don't know the correct approach.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util) to do this easily, eg.

```
use List::Util qw(min max);
my @arr = (33, 32, 8, 100);
print min(@arr)," ", max(@arr), "\n";
```

Answer (score 16):

The provided solutions are good, but if you want to implement it yourself it's pretty straightforward:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (33, 32, 8, 100);
my ($min, $max);

for (@array) {
    $min = $_ if !$min || $_ < $min;
    $max = $_ if !$max || $_ > $max
};

print "min: $min\n";
print "max: $max\n";
```

Comment: breaks if minimum or maximum is zero.  Should use `!defined($min)` in place of `!$min` to test if `$min` is undefined (and same for `$max` of couse).

Answer (score 3):

For numbers:

```
    my ($min,$max) = (sort {$a <=> $b} @array)[0,-1];
```

For strings:

```
    my ($min,$max) = (sort {$a cmp $b} @array)[0,-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to do this without needing libraries:

```
my @array = (33, 32, 8, 100);
my ($max,$min)=(-1e99,1e99); # Initialize to values outside anything in your list
map {$max=$_ if ($_>$max); $min=$_ if($_<$min);} @array;
print "max=$max, min=$min\n";
```

Comment: When the result is not collected use `for` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) which has been released with the Perl distribution since v5.7.3 so probably doesn't need installing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw/ max min /;

my @data = (33, 32, 8, 100);

say min @data;
say max @data;
```

**output**

```
8
100
```

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse, if you want both the maxium and minimum value of a list at the same time, it is more efficient to fetch both at once; it only has to perform 3 order comparisons per 2 items of data, rather than 4. This may matter if the data sets are big enough.

`List::Util` doesn't provide a `minmax` function but `List::MoreUtils` does.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );

my ( $min, $max ) = minmax @data;

say $min;
say $max;
```

Comment: Actually I've just seen ikegami already gave the `List::MoreUtils` answer above. Sorry for the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I think [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Statistics::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~brianl/Statistics-Lite-3.2/Lite.pm) to compute min,max etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`List::Util` module](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil), which it is recommended to get acquainted with anyway, just like `List::MoreUtils`:

```
D:\ :: perl -MList::Util=max -lwe "print max 324, 43, 53, 3532, 43"
3532

D:\ :: perl -MList::Util=min -lwe "print min 324, 43, 53, 3532, 43"
43
```

Answer (score 0):

[List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) has the "max" and "min" functions that you can use to directly find the maximum and minimum given a list of numbers. Check if you can use that. You may also sort the array and then determine the highest and lowest number

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but this is how I did it without any modules.

```
sub min {
    my $min = shift;
    foreach (@_) {
        $min = $_ if $_ < $min;
    }
    return $min;
}

sub max {
    my $max = shift;
    foreach (@_) {
        $max = $_ if $_ > $max;
    }
    return $max;
}
```