# In Perl, how can I find the overall smallest value in two arrays?

Tags: perl, minimum

I have two array which contain integer. eg:

```
@arr1 = ( 2, 5, 6)
@arr2 = ( 1, 4, 7)
```

How to find the minimum value between this two array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find maximum and minimum value in an array of integers in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701210/how-to-find-maximum-and-minimum-value-in-an-array-of-integers-in-perl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `min` function of [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) module:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw( min );

my @arr1 = ( 2, 5, 6 );
my @arr2 = ( 1, 4, 7 );
print min(@arr1, @arr2), "\n";
```

Output:

```
1
```

Without module, by using `sort` function:

```
my ($min) = sort { $a <=> $b } @arr1, @arr2;
print "$min\n";
```

Comment: Why bother suggesting a "without List::Util" scenario? List::Util is core and therefore always available. Furthermore, the `min` function runs in linear time, whereas a sort would take `n log n` time to sort the complete list, only to take the lowest element of the result.

Comment: @LeoNerd: I know its core module. I just gave another way to do. :)

Comment: @serenesat Thank for the answer. If i want to print the array which contain the smallest value instead of the value. How should i do?

Comment: @tim: Take the smallest value from the arrays into two different variables. Now with an if condition check which variable have minimum value and print the correspondence array.

Answer (score 1):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992982/100754) is memory inefficient.

If `@arr1` and `@arr2` are large, the impact of constructing the list `(@arr1, @arr2)` just to pass it to `min` can be significant.

Instead, use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( min );

my @arr1 = ( 2, 5, 6 );
my @arr2 = ( 1, 4, 7 );

print min( min(@arr1), min(@arr2) ), "\n";
```