# Perl: find the max and min values in the array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I have the structure below in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    'firstitem' => {
        '1' => ["A","99"],
        '2' => ["B","88"],
        '3' => ["C","77"],
    },
    'seconditem' => {
        '3' => ["C","100"],
        '4' => ["D","200"],
        '5' => ["E","300"],
    },
);
```

I am looking for a way to find the max number and min number in the array of each hash.
So the output will be

```
firstitem: max:99, min:77
seconditem: max:300, min:100
```

My idea is sorting the secondary key first and then do the bubble sort or other sorts in the for loop. It looks like not very elegant and smart.

```
    foreach my $k1 (keys %hash) {
        my $second_hash_ref = $hash{$k1};                   
        my @sorted_k2 = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{$second_hash_ref}; 
        foreach my $i (0..$#sorted_k3){ 
            #bubble sort or other sort
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to sort the second key first and then iterate value based on the sorted key and then do the bubble sort in the for loop. Posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find maximum and minimum value in an array of integers in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701210/how-to-find-maximum-and-minimum-value-in-an-array-of-integers-in-perl)

Comment: @MattJacob I did some googling about this question, and I found some similar one. But my data structure is a little different. Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) is a core module that provides the `min` and `max` functions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(min max);

my %hash = (
    'firstitem' => {
        '1' => ["A","99"],
        '2' => ["B","88"],
        '3' => ["C","77"],
    },
    'seconditem' => {
        '3' => ["C","100"],
        '4' => ["D","200"],
        '5' => ["E","300"],
    },
);

for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
    my @numbers = map { $_->[1] } values(%{$hash{$key}});
    printf("%s: max: %d, min: %d\n", $key, max(@numbers), min(@numbers));
}
```

Output:

```
firstitem: max: 99, min: 77
seconditem: max: 300, min: 100
```

Comment: List::MoreUtils provides `minmax`, which is more efficient than calling both `min` and `max`.

Comment: @MattJacob What can I write explicitly instead of using `$_->[1]`?

Comment: @Luke I don't understand the question.

Comment: @MattJaco You used `$_->[1]` in your for loop. I know it calls the elements in the array. I just want to learn any other ways to call it? Like more explicitly ways instead of `$_->[1]`

Comment: @Luke What could be more explicit than the element at position 1 of an array reference?

Comment: @MattJacob Yes!

Comment: @Luke Is it possible that there's a language barrier here? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @MattJacob OH. I misunderstood. Nvm. haha. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

Once you get to the second level what you need is the *whole list* of numbers, so to be able to find max and min of the lot. Since you need the extreme values for all arrays within the subkey you don't need to iterate over the second-level keys.

Also, you can fetch all array content unless the number is guaranteed to be at the specific place. Then use `grep` with [Scalar::Util::looks_like_number](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#looks_like_number) to filter out elements that aren't numbers.

Finally, there is no benefit in sorting the keys.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';
use List::MoreUtils 'minmax';

my %hash = ( 
    'firstitem' => {
        '1' => ["A","99"], '2' => ["B","88"], '3' => ["C","77"],
    },  
    'seconditem' => {
        '3' => ["C","100"], '4' => ["D","200"], '5' => ["E","300"],
    },  
);


foreach my $k1 (keys %hash) 
{
    my @nums = 
        grep { looks_like_number($_) } 
        map  { @{ $hash{$k1}{$_} } }
        keys %{$hash{$k1}};

    my ($min, $max) = minmax @nums;

    say "$k1: max = $max, min = $min";
}
```

This prints the expected values.  If your real hash is exactly as shown you can extract arrayrefs directly by `values %{$hash{$k1}}`, with `map { @$_ }` to dereference them.

Since you need both extremes a good fit is `minmax` from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.425/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm), which is "*the most efficient possible algorithm*" for the job. The algorithm's performance is fully realized in the XS version of the module while the Perl version has some overhead.

Also note the core [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) module, where individual `min` and `max` are, among other utilities.

Comment: Awesome. It is a pretty solution. It is good to know `grep` with **Scalar::Util::looks_like_number**. Thanks for your always quick respond.