# How to find the max and min values in a Hash using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to find a simple way to find the max and min values of a hash array using Perl.  It seems I am getting the max value but not the min value.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(min max);

# defines TimeStamp => time which is coming from a csv file
my %timess = (
 'TimeStamp' => 127000.2323,
 'TimeStamp' => 124000.2323,
 'TimeStamp' => 125000.2323,
 'TimeStamp' => 128000.2323,
 'TimeStamp' => 129000.2323
);

foreach my $row (values %timess) {
    my $maxTime = max($row);
    my $minTime = min($row);
    printf("max: %d, min: %d\n", $maxTime, $minTime);
}
```

The output

```
max: 129000, min: 129000
```

I have tried different methods even posted in this link:  [Perl: find the max and min values in the array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534911/perl-find-the-max-and-min-values-in-the-array-of-hashes)

Any feedback will be great!

Comment: A hash cannot contain duplicate keys. Your hash only contains a single key/value pair - the one that is at the end of the list you use to initialise the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem is that you only pass a single scalar to `min` and to `max`. You want `@$row` (short for `@{ $row }`) instead of `$row`. The loop is also needless/incorrect.

Fixed:

```perl
use List::Utils qw( max min );

my $min = min( @{ $timess{ TimeStamp } } );
my $max = max( @{ $timess{ TimeStamp } } );
```

That said, it's a bit more efficient to use `minmax` from List::MoreUtils than to use both `min` and `max`.

```perl
use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );

my ( $min, $max ) = minmax( @{ $timess{ TimeStamp } } );
```

Comment: Good one too!!!

Comment: no prob, cool without the loop, thank you @ikegami, I tested it and it works!

Comment: `@ikegami`,  if there is an array of hashes, then a loop is necessary? correct?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, thanks to @jhnc advice

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(min max);

# defines TimeStamp => time which is coming from a csv file
my %timess = (
 'TimeStamp' => [
     127000.2323,
     124000.2323,
     125000.2323,
     128000.2323,
     129000.2323
     ]
);

foreach my $row (keys %timess) {
  my $maxTime = max(@{$timess{$row}});
  my $minTime = min(@{$timess{$row}}); 
  printf("max: %d, min: %d\n", $maxTime, $minTime);
}
```

Or use List::MoreUtils suggested by @ikegami which is without the for loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );

# defines TimeStamp => time which is coming from a csv file
my %timess = (
 'TimeStamp' => [
     127000.2323,
     124000.2323,
     125000.2323,
     128000.2323,
     129000.2323
     ]
);

my ( $minTime, $maxTime ) = minmax( @{ $timess{ TimeStamp } } );
printf("max: %d, min: %d\n", $maxTime, $minTime);
```

Output:

```
max: 129000, min: 124000
```

Comment: Done!! Yup so it’s not confusing

Comment: Don't need the loop when using `min` and `max` either. And you shouldn't have that loop.  That's the point of my answer.

Comment: Ah got ya yeah better! I think not point looping if those min and max can handle it